# Python: Creating a Loop to update data

Tags: python, loops, cpu-usage, psutil

I have a small python script this is printing out how much CPU usage the machine is using, I am running into an issue, that it won't update after there is a change in percentage, I put it under an infinite while loop but it stays at the last percent that was recorded, here is my code any help or advice would be splendid:

```
cpu_time = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1,percpu=False)
var=1
while var==1:
    if cpu_time < 10:
        print "CPU usage: "+str(cpu_time)
    elif cpu_time <=25:
        print "CPU usage: "+str(cpu_time)
```

etc... for 50, 75 and 90 percent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is now, `cpu_time` is never changing. You want to update the `cpu_time` inside the loop:

```
while True:
    cpu_time = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1,percpu=False)
    if cpu_time < 10:
        print "CPU usage: "+str(cpu_time)
    elif cpu_time <=25:
        print "CPU usage: "+str(cpu_time)
```

Comment: oh wow, that was incredibly easy and stupid of me! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to refresh the `cpu_time` value : put it inside the loop

```
var=1
while var==1:
    cpu_time = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1,percpu=False)

    if cpu_time < 10:
        print "CPU usage: "+str(cpu_time)
    elif cpu_time <=25:
        print "CPU usage: "+str(cpu_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function that returns the CPU data into the loop, not outside:

```
while True:
    cpu_time = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1,percpu=False)
    if cpu_time < 10:
        print "CPU usage: "+str(cpu_time)
    elif cpu_time <=25:
        print "CPU usage: "+str(cpu_time)
```

Hope that helps.